# ASP.NET MVC JQuery Validation Not Triggering through Submit Input .click

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems on my validation for my login. My `JQuery` is not triggering that is why the `Json` data is not passed. I want it to trigger the `JQuery` first before going to the controller. It goes to the controller but the problem is the `.submit`() function was not triggered that is why the ajax data is not passed. Thanks.

**LogIn.cshtml**

```
@model DTS.Models.User
<h2>LogIn</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new {@id = "Username" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { @id = "Password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-default" id="Login"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script>
    $("#Login").submit(function () {
        var dataObject = { UsernName: $("#Username").val(), Password: $("#Password").val() };

        $.ajax({
            url: Url.Action("LogIn", "User"),
            type: "POST",
            data: dataObject,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(result)
            {
                if (result.toString()=="Success!") {
                    alert(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(result);
                }
            },
            error: function(result)
            {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    })

</script>
```

**UserController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(User user)
        {
            string message = "";
            DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
            param.Add("@Username", user.Username);
            param.Add("@UserID", user.Password);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (DapperORM.ExecuteReturnScalar<User>("LogInUser", param) == null)
                {
                    message = "Success!";
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Username or Password is incorrect!";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Required fields.";
            }

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Document");
            }
        }
```

Comment: A submit button does not have a `.submit()` event - a `<form>` does - its `$("form").submit(function () { .... }` (or give the `<form>` and `id` attribute and use that as the selector)

Comment: And then you need to cancel the default submit as well or you will submitting twice

Comment: wrap you submit button code inside $(document).ready(function(){ ...here... });

Comment: And use `var dataObject = $(this).serialize();` (you already have a typo when creating your object - you do not have a property name `UsernName`)

Comment: i'm sorry sir. that is not supposed to be .submit but rather .click but still not working.

Comment: No. It should be handling the forms `.submit()` event (so that validation is triggered and can be checked). But why in the world are you using ajax - why would the user want to stay on the same page when logged in - they do not want to login again)

Comment: I'm using ajax because i want to display the error.

Comment: The do it correctly and make a normal submit, and if add an error to `ModelState` (using `ModelState.AddModelError(...);` and return the view

Comment: How sir? I have not used ModelState.AddModelError()

Comment: `if (xxxx) { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is incorrect"); if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return view(user); } else { return RedirectToAction(...);` and that message will be displayed in the `@Html.ValidationSummary()`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // rest code goes here

    });
});
```

Here I have made two modifications.

1. First, I have wrapped the code in document.ready().
2. Second, I have applied `submit` event on form instead of button.
3. Third, I have used `e.preventDefault()`. This will prevent submit button click from doing a full page postback.

Comment: No it will not! If the script is after the html which OP has shown, then `document.ready()` is not required. And a submit button does not have a `.submit()` event

Comment: yes..I have corrected my answer. Added submit event on form.